# iOS Spotlight search doesn't work when Siri adding its words

Tags: ios, search, spotlight, siri

I'm trying to index my app products to spotlight, it's work well if I'm search one of the keywords I've set:

```
CSSearchableItemAttributeSet *attibuteSet = [[CSSearchableItemAttributeSet alloc] initWithItemContentType:(__bridge NSString *)kUTTypeImage];
attibuteSet.keywords = @[self.name, self.desc, self.regularPrice];
```

For example I've a Sweat-shirt called "Christmas". If I write "Christmas" in spotlight search it's ok. If I use Siri "Find me Christmas" it doesn't work. Or more general "Find me a t-shirt" with t-shirt indexed it's doesn't work too.

What are the best practices to have it's content index doing well with Siri ?

Comment: Think only NSUserActivity has Siri support.

Comment: I didn't know thanks !

Comment: It's change nothing when combining with NSUserActivity